# How can I move a rectangle by CZML in Cesium?

Tags: gis, cesiumjs, czml

I would like to ask that I defined a rectangle in czml, but we know that the rectangle is determined by four dimensions[Cesium.Rectangle(west, south, east, north)]. How should I fill in the "position" if I want to move the rectangle? I tried "cartographicDegrees" and "wsenDegrees", but I couldn't move according to time.

```
{
        "id": "rectangle",
        "rectangle": {
            "coordinates": {
                "wsenDegrees": [118.99, 24.99, 119.01, 25.01] //how can I change this position?
            },
            "height": 1000,
            "fill": true,
        },
```

Answer (score 0):

I think that you need to remove the element first, and then create a new one with different position.